# Be + Infinitive Passive Construction

Tags: grammar, be, periphrastic-modals

I was wondering if given the formal construction 'be + infinitive' I may do it passive like these:

> The president is to be visited by…

or past meaning

> He was to be visited (… and he was)

or

> He was to have been visited. (… he wasn't)

Comment: Your examples make perfect sense. Are you confused about something?

Comment: Yes, cause I came across a certan kinda passive construction (to be + past parteciple) like this: There's much work to be done but in cases like this one The room is to be painted  I saw that the construction is the same of Be+infinitive but actually it's passive. So i was wondering I could create the same kinda construction but used in a different context, as be+infinitive is mainly used in formal writings. Hope i put u across my point

Comment: This construction often appears as a literal rendering of the Latin gerundive (http://blogs.transparent.com/latin/gerunds-vs-gerundives/), and thus also, I would expect, in English writers who take after Latin models.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).